# JavaScript Closure incorrect behavior

Tags: javascript, closures

Here is a small snippet of code where I feel the closure function has a weird behavior ...

```js
var arr = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];
var someFn;

arr.forEach(function(val, idx) {
  if (!someFn) {
    someFn = function() {
      console.log(`B: ${idx} : ${val}`);
    };
  }
  console.log(`A: ${idx} : ${val}`);
  someFn();
});
```

The final console output is ...

> ```
> A: 0 : 5
> B: 0 : 5
> A: 1 : 6
> B: 0 : 5
> A: 2 : 7
> B: 0 : 5
> A: 3 : 8
> B: 0 : 5
> A: 4 : 9
> B: 0 : 5
> A: 5 : 0
> B: 0 : 5
> ```

I expect `someFn` to process the incremental value when the forEach is processing, but it always outputs the first value which is `"idx: 0, val: 5"`.

I dont think this is the right behavior because `someFn` is creating a closure which encloses the variables `idx` and `val` and both those variables are changing in the outer function.

Appreciate if someone can kindly explain this behavior.

Comment: I think it's because you declared `someFn()` with a current value of `idx` and `val` and once you keep calling it you are not passing new values of them.

Comment: Your if condition is messing it up: Use this :

var arr = [5,6,7,8,9,0];
  var someFn;

  arr.forEach(function(val, idx) {
      someFn = function(){
        console.log(`B: ${idx} : ${val}`);
      };
       
    someFn();
  });

and it will work.

Comment: @baao the problem has nothing to do with **template literals**. So I'm voting to reopen this.

Comment: Of course it has, read the answers to the dupe and think about when the template string is evaluated in above code.

Comment: It's because `someFn` was created on the first call of the anounymous function (callback) passed to `forEach`. Each function call creates it own closure. So for all the iterations `someFn` will have the closure of the first iteration, thus showing only those values.

Comment: @baao this is not about template literals. This is about closure behaviors.

Comment: @baao Na man it is not about that.

Comment: @Praj try removing the if condition.

Comment: @baao I just tried it without any use of template literals, and the problem still occur. And none of the answers in the duplicate link is talking about the problem.

Comment: @ibrahim mahrir
So this is about how forEach works. But I am still not willing to believe what you explained (respectfully disagreeing) because someFn is a function created inside the forEach callback. It has to inherit all the variables of the created closure.

Comment: ok reopened it @ibrahimmahrir

Comment: @Fahad removing the if condition will create a new someFn and that will fix the issue ... no doubt about that.


The above code is a real life scenario where I dont want to recreate the someFn for optimization reasons. Of course, my solution was to use a for loop instead of forEach and that fixed the problem and also create someFn once only.


I just want to understand the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [**other answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/111111/6647153) on SO:

> a closure is a stack frame which is allocated when a function starts its execution...

So every function call creates its own closure.

What `forEach` does is that it takes a function (callback) and call it multiple times (passing the element from the array along with its index and the array). So, each iteration of `forEach` creates a new closure.

You are defining `someFn` on the first iteration (never get redeclared after that), so the closure it is trapped in is the closure of the first iteration. Thus the only available values are the ones on the first iteration.

**The closure is not related to the function itself, it is related to its calls**.

Example:

```js
function theFunction(value) {
  return function() {
    return value;
  };
}

var someFn1 = theFunction("Ibrahim");
var someFn2 = theFunction("John");

console.log("someFn1: ", someFn1());
console.log("someFn2: ", someFn2());
```

In the example, each call to `theFunction` creates a new closure. `someFn1` and `someFn2`, although they're generated by the same function, but don't have access to the same closure.

The equivalent to `theFunction` in your code is the anounymous function passed to `forEach` that gets executed (and thus creating clousures) as many times as there is elements in the array.

Comment: I do understand this. But I believe your answer is correct. Though I think that I understand closures really well, but it is so easy to fall for such traps. Thanks and I voted for you.

Answer (score 0):

> I expect `someFn` is creating a closure which encloses the variables `idx` and `val` and both those variables are changing in the outer function.

No, they don't change. They are new variables that are instantiated with every call to the outer function. The two variables from the first iteration, over which the closure that was created there did close, keep their values.

To get the expected behaviour, you can use a loop without a function, where you only declare two variables:

```
var arr = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];

for (var [idx, val] of arr.entries()) {
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ global variables
  if (!someFn) {
    var someFn = function() {
      console.log(`B: ${idx} : ${val}`);
    };
  }
  console.log(`A: ${idx} : ${val}`);
  someFn();
}
```

Though [usually that's exactly what we try to prevent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/1048572) :-)